# IntellijIDEA 2017.3 does not recognize <jar> ant task. Any fix?

Tags: intellij-idea

Any <jar> task in an Ant build file in IDEA Community 2017.3 makes the IDE to display an error message, as shown below.  However, the ant task runs fine and the jar is created.  So this seems to be just a bug of the IDE.  Is there something one can do to fix it?  It's just distracting being reminded of a nonexistent error.

[image]

Comment: What Ant version do you use: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/build-file-properties.html ? It seems to work fine on my machine

Comment: I use the bundled Ant: 1.9.4 (according to the execution tab of the "Build File Properties" dialog box)